# Double $match in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have two collections as

## Col1

```
{"_id":ObjectId("5c13fa0178cd81112f1d5ba5"),
"common_id": 123,
"context":"app"   
}
```

#### context has different options as "app", "db", "network"

## Col2

```
{"_id":ObjectId("5c13fa0178cd81112f1d5b34"),
"common_id":123,
"name":"android-app"
"status":"Up"
}
```

#### status has different options as "Up","Down","Degraded"

I am interested in getting result like:

```
{
"name":"android-app",
}
```

Only if context is app and status is up for item with same common_id.

I have tried as:

```
col1.aggregate([{"$match": {"context":"app"}},
                  {"$lookup": {"from":col2,
                               "localField": "common_id",
                               "foreignField": "common_id",
                               "as": "output_info"}},
                  {"$unwind": {"path": "$output_info"}}, 
                  {"$match": "$output_info.status":"Up"},  
                  {
                    "$project":{
                      "$output_info.name":1
                  }}
                  ])
```

But its getting error..

Comment: Remove `$` from the second `$match` stage and the `$project`. And the `$project` stage should be `{ $project:{ name: "$output_info.name" }}`

Comment: as an aggregation debugging tip, try adding in the stages of the pipeline in 1 at a time until you see where the breakdown is. Your first match is most likely not an issue. assuming your actual collection 2 name is "collection 2 name"  there isn't an issue there. but in case that wasn't thought of all fields passed in during lookup need to be strings.

Comment: also its very helpful to write your queries in a mongodb editor like NoSqlBooster (free) which will a lot of the time tell you where your errors are syntactically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, you've some syntax errors in your query

1. `$lookup` from table is not enclosed with double quotes
2. `$match` stage missing `{}`,
3. `$match` and `$project` field name should not start with `$`

query

```
db.col1.aggregate([
    {"$match": {"context":"app"}},
    {"$lookup": {
        "from":"col2",
        "localField": "common_id",
        "foreignField": "common_id",
        "as": "output_info"
    }},
    {"$unwind": {"path": "$output_info"}}, 
    {"$match": {"output_info.status":"Up"}}, 
    {"$project":{"output_info.name":1}}
])
```

Answer (score 1):

My initial suggestion when it comes to mongodb would be to combine the two collections into one and not use an aggregate at all. This data sounds extremely related and combinable. Once combined you could do a query

db.col.find({ context: "app", status: "Up" })

If you must have an aggregate I can look more deeply at the query.